# ValueError in python.

Tags: python, primes

Here is my code:

```
def f(x): return x%2!=0 and x%3!=0

primes = filter(f , range (6,50))

for x in primes:
    for a in filter(f, range(2,x-1)):       
      if x%a == 0:
        primes.remove(x);

print(primes)
```

I get this error:

```
File "primes.py", line 12, in <module>
    primes.remove(x);
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

But the funny thing is if i write like that:

```
def f(x): return x%2!=0 and x%3
primes = filter(f , range (6,20))

for x in primes:
    for a in filter(f, range(2,x-1)): 

            if x%a == 0:
                primes.remove(x);

print(primes)
```

Why? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the result:

```
>>> primes = filter(f , range (6,50))
>>> primes
[7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
```

You have the value 35 here, which is 5*7. In your nested loop, when `a` is 5, the condition is met and 35 is removed from the list of `primes`; when `a` goes to 7, the condition is met again, but this time 35 is already removed, so a exception is raised.

So a simple fixed is like the one below. such that `x` is removed only once when the condition is first met:

```
for x in primes:
    for a in filter(f, range(2,x-1)):
        if x%a == 0:
            primes.remove(x)
            break
```

But now it will skip the element right after a non-prime number, such as 95 in this list:

```
primes=[7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 53, 55, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 85, 89, 91, 95, 97]
```

which is fixed by making a slice of `primes`:

```
for x in primes[:]:
    for a in filter(f, range(2,x-1)):
        if x%a == 0:
            primes.remove(x)
            break
```

Comment: another problem arises when i let to loop run untill 100. it produces 95 as prime number. i cant make sense of it. does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: Oh, that's because once the loop gets `91`, it removes `91` (7*13) and `prime` becomes one element shorter. Moving to the next element in the next round now skips `95` and goes directly to `97`. So it can be fixed with creating a slice of `primes`, which is a new list. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put in some print statements to see what's going on:

```
In [81]: %paste
def f(x): return x%2!=0 and x%3!=0

primes = filter(f , range (6,50))
print primes

for x in primes:
    for a in filter(f, range(2,x-1)):
      if x%a == 0:
        print x
        primes.remove(x);

print(primes)

## -- End pasted text --
[7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49]
25
35
35
```

So your problem is that you're producing the number 35 twice (and you get an exception the second time because it's not there after you remove it the first time!)